# Reinitializing the initial DDL data in Hibernate/Spring Boot MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have an application in Spring Boot, using MySQL database.
My application has 3 Entities:
Client, Service, and ClientService serving as a @ManyToOne connector between them, with additional field of ServiceDate.

My application.yml config:

```yaml
spring:
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db?useSSL=false
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: admin
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

I am using DDL script schema.sql to create the tables (I'm not sure if this isn't a requirement with MySQL database, but I'm doing it nevertheless), and data.sql to load some initial data into Client and Service tables. Then in Main() I add some relations between them into ClientService table, everything works.
Now, as I start the application for the 1st time on clean schema, the tables are being created, and populated with test data.
After the application ends, tables and data inside in MySQL database persist (I know I can change this with **ddl-auto: create-drop**, but I don't want tables to be dropped at the end of the program execution). I want to drop **only the data** every time I start the application, depending on what I declare in SQL - I added lines:

```
DELETE FROM Client;
DELETE FROM Service;
DELETE FROM ClientService;
```

at the beggining of data.sql. When I run the application **for the 2nd time** (when tables in DB are already created & populated), the application fails on DELETE statement:

```
2024-01-18T18:23:15.406+01:00  WARN 13392 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of file [...\target\classes\data.sql]: DELETE FROM Clients
2024-01-18T18:23:15.407+01:00  INFO 13392 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-18T18:23:15.409+01:00  INFO 13392 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-01-18T18:23:15.416+01:00  INFO 13392 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-01-18T18:23:15.425+01:00  INFO 13392 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-18T18:23:15.446+01:00 ERROR 13392 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of file [...\target\classes\data.sql]: DELETE FROM Clients
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
```

I tried using spring.sql.init.data-sources property to initialize data from some custom file, but the result is the same.
Is it safe to assume, that schema script can hold only CREATE TABLE and data initialization scripts accept only INSERT INTO statements? If yes, how can I force data deletion during scripts execution (without using entityManager/Repository deleteAll() method)?

Comment: Can you share the DDL please? I guess there are some foreign keys, which must be deleted first

Comment: data.sql can hold delete statements. However it looks like you are misspelling the table name. Is it Client or Clients?

Comment: @Jens Holy moly, you're completely right. FKs are the thing I didn't think about when deleting. I changed the order of DELETE to delete ClientService data first, and it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**The answer thanks to Jens**:

In this case ClientService table holds Forign Keys to the tables Service and Client, when deleting data it is this table that needs to be cleared first, and only after all FKs are gone, the data from "main" tables can be cleared as well.